# How to make Woocommerce shortcodes display a notice if no products found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Currently, if we use a shortcode like `[products paginate="true" limit="30" on_sale="true"]`, but there are no products to display, nothing is returned. There is no information like `No products founds`. I would like to modify this functionality

I found an `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results` filter that at first glance can change it, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to modify it

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results', function ($results) {
    if (!empty($results->ids)) {
        return $results;
    } else {
        echo 'No products found';
    }
});
```

Should I do it differently? There is a better, more flexible way? If so, how?

Comment: No, that filter is used to manipulate the database query that selects the products in the first place. I think `woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results` is what you should hook into. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php#L680 Output whatever message you want to display when there were no products found there.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since **@CBroe** posted his answer as a comment, I decided to copy it as the answer as it is correct and it will be easier for other users to find it:*

> No, that filter is used to manipulate the database query that selects the products in the first place. I think `woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results` is what you should hook into. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php#L680 Output whatever message you want to display when there were no products found there.